# How to set a gap in the constraints using google or-tools

Tags: java, optimization, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem using Google or-tools

`minimize f = x1 + x2`

with the constraints

```
x1 = 0 or 100 <= x1 <= 2000
x2 = 0 or 100 <= x2 <= 2000
x1 + 4 * x2 >= 650
```

What Solver is most appropriate for this problem?

How do I define these constraints? (I'm using in Java)

I can model this with 3 constraints per variable (as pointed out by sascha)

```
x1 >= a1 * 100
x1 <= a1 * 2000
a1 = 0, 1 (binary)

x2 >= a2 * 100
x2 <= a2 * 2000
a2 = 0, 1 (binary)
```

However, `Solver.makeConstraint()` requires the constraints to be on the form

```
L <= c1*x1 + c2*x2
```

```java
...
MPConstraint ct = solver.makeConstraint(L, infinity);
ct.setCoefficient(x1, c1);
ct.setCoefficient(x2, c2);
...
```

L, c1 and c2 needs to be numbers and not other variables.
In my case I would like to do something like

```java
...
// x1 >= a1 * 100
MPConstraint ct = solver.makeConstraint(a1 * 100, infinity);
ct.setCoefficient(x1, 1);
...
```

Comment: Ignoring, that this is trivially solved by hand, there are at least two approaches: 1) Integer-programming, where you have to linearize this (see [section 7.1](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf)) or ortools CP-SAT solver. The former should scale better with big instances, the latter allows easier modelling (e.g. by introducing binary-variable and posting reified constraint with `OnlyEnforceIf`). For both solvers, there should be a documentation that will allow you to implement it. If not, update your question with a more detailed problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is of course a severe simplification of my real problem. I've updated the original question with additional details.

Comment: In regards to your update: just use your school-math: `x1 >= 100 * a1 < subtract x1 from both sides-> 0 >= 100 * a1 - x1 <multiply -1 to sides-> 0 <= -100 * a1 + x1` See also: *canonical form of lp* (there is more than one; often depending on solver assumptions; but they share the general core)